# how can i do first variable like second variable in php

Tags: php

my code is

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/scripts/script1.php")
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
```

some time  my   URL  come  like

```
www.example.com/scripts/script1.php?var1=value1&var2=value2
```

How can do  that  with  PHP

URL  like  function....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in PHP

```
  <?php 
       if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/scripts/script1.php")!==false)
        {
            echo 'yes';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'no';
        }
```

Comment: I have a doubt, why is there two `==` ? Is that for checking case-sensitivity?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger - that is the absolute equality operator

Comment: `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.` From the [Manual](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues). @ICanHasCheezburger

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on [Shankar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21968622/558021)

```
   $result = "no";
   if( strpos( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ], "/scripts/script1.php" ) !== false ) {
        $result = "yes";
   }
```

By setting the default value for the variable, you can make your code more concise and improve readability.